# C каким типом надо вызывать ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, spring

У меня есть контроллер

```
@RestController
public class BookController {
    @GetMapping("/find-by-name/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<BookEntity> findByName(@PathVariable String name) {
      ...
```

если имя найдено, то в этом методе я возвращаю

```
return  ResponseEntity.ok(book);
```

если нет, то

```
return new ResponseEntity("name= " + name + " not found", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
```

Все работает, но компилятор ругается:

```
Raw use of parameterized class 'ResponseEntity' 
Unchecked assignment: 'org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity' to 'org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<BookEntity>' 
Unchecked call to 'ResponseEntity(T, HttpStatus)' as a member of raw type 'org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity'
```

Попробовал сделать так (этот вариант нашел на сайте [spring.io](https://spring.io))

```
public ResponseEntity<?> findByName(@PathVariable String name) {
...
return new ResponseEntity<>("name= " + name + " not found", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
```

Та ошибка ушла, но теперь ругается на эту строку:

```
Generic wildcard types should not be used in return types
```

Код работает в обоих вариантах, но хотелось бы понять как все-таки это реализовать правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Возвращать `ResponseEntity<BookEntity>` нельзя, т.к. метод у вас не всегда возвращает `BookEntity`. Поэтому получаете предупреждение компилятора, когда используете сырой тип (англ. raw type).

Правильно использовать `ResponseEntity<?>` или `ResponseEntity<Object>`.

Вот такой код компилируется без проблем:

```
public class A {

  public class BookEntity {
  }

  public ResponseEntity<?> findByName(String name) {
    if (!name.isEmpty()) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(new BookEntity(), HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
      return new ResponseEntity<>("", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
  }
}
```

но очевидно вы получаете предупреждения статического анализатора. В большинстве случаев использование неограниченного wildcard-а в возвращаемом типе плохо, т.к.
это требует от клиента вашего кода анализировать реальный тип возвращаемого объекта в `runtime`.

В данном случае клиентом выступает spring и он поддерживает разные возвращаемые типы (т.к. spring не использует ваш метод статически, т.е. на этапе компиляции, а использует reflection и анализирует тип объекта уже на этапе выполнения). Так что в этом случае безопасно игнорировать это предупреждение (вы можете его отключить для метода если это возможно - зависит от инструмента, который вы используете).

Другой вариант - не использовать неограниченный wildcard. Т.е. использовать `ResponseEntity<Object>`.

И, немного не по теме, если объект не найден, то нужно возвращать http код 404 (not found), как в примере выше.

Comment: У меня он тоже компилится, я же писал, что оба варианта работают. Это варнинг, причем на сам знак <?>. Вот если указать ResponseEntity<Object>, тогда все ОК. А изначальный код с ResponseEntity<BookEntity> - это нас на курсах так учили, там на такие мелочи внимая не обращаешь.

Comment: Пропустил вначале. Сейчас добавил пояснение, почему выдает предупреждение.

Answer (score 0):

```java
return new ResponseEntity<>("name= " + name + " not found", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
```

Или

```java
return new ResponseEntity<>(book, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: Я так и сделал во втором варианте, но теперь компилятору не нравиться: <?>

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Попробуй <?> заменить на <String>

Comment: В этом случае на проходит ResponseEntity.ok(book);

Comment: Тогда new ResponseEntity<>(book, HttpStatus.OK);